# Storyboard segue cover vertical transition on iPhone 4 and 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uistoryboard

I'm building an app that supports iOS5+ and is made for both iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 screen sizes. It currently uses storyboards for most of the flow.

When I do an animated modal segue that covers vertical, there is a half inch of white space on top of the view -- only on a 3.5 inch screen (iPhone 4). There is no whitespace on iPhone 5, as the view is completely filled with content.

This is confusing to me because I'm resizing the view in the viewDidLoad to match the screen size. I've also tried setting the background color to clear, but still no dice. Here's what I'm doing to resize it:

```
[self.view height:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It was just my background image (UIImage at the very back of the view). I had it sized for iPhone 5 and fixed to the bottom of the view. The whitespace sticking out the top was just the top of the background image... I'm not sure why I thought it would magically get cut off.